# Can't install with composer

Tags: composer-php

There seems to be an issue with the certificate of https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json. Even when I try to open it in a browser it shouts a certificate error.
Therefore I can't install any package and I'm getting this error:
`The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Peer certificate CN='packagist.org' did not match expected CN='repo.packagist.org'` . Is there any workaround?

I'm on a fresh MacOS Mojave. It's been a few years since I was setting up composer on a mac for myself so in case this is really basic, sorry :)

Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was just a temporary error with packagist. Murphy's laws ensured it was exactly when I was trying to install packages.

It works now without any issue.